# Bindonce on ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bindonce

What is the effect of using the native bindonce on an ng-repeat object? For example:

```
ng-repeat="data in ::stuff"
```

Does this mean every item in 'stuff' has the watcher removed? Or do you still need to apply bindonce to every child bind in the repeat like this?

```
<div ng-repeat="data in ::stuff">
  <span ng-bind="::data.thing"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `data in ::stuff`, the array is bound once and a `$watcher` is not created after bound the first time, and therefore any changes to that array will not update your `ng-repeat`'s view.

However, unless you have `::data.thing` changes to individual objects will still be registered. Those watchers belong to the object itself and not the shallow contents of the array.

See my plunkr below.

```html
<iframe src="http://embed.plnkr.co/3gbmI2kqd3rT7z0GEyK7/"></iframe>
```